How To Make Custom Loss Function in Keras/Tensorflow
I will briefly describe my issue and get to the point quickly. I am creating Jupyter notebook for classification prediction. I am using Keras Tensorflow for probability prediction. The classification nature is binary classification. My specific goal is to optimize the model for ROC AUC score. Here is my model definition.
train_x, train_y = df[predictors].iloc[train_idx].values, df['target'].iloc[train_idx].values
valid_x, valid_y = df[predictors].iloc[valid_idx].values, df['target'].iloc[valid_idx].values
train_x = np.asarray(train_x).astype('float32')
train_y = np.asarray(train_y).astype('float32')
valid_x = np.asarray(valid_x).astype('float32')
valid_y = np.asarray(valid_y).astype('float32')
# Define FNN model architecture
num_features = train_x.shape[1]
clf = Sequential([
    Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(num_features,)),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile the model with custom loss function and ROC AUC metric
clf.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss=custom_loss,
            metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])

# Define early stopping callback
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
# Define learning rate scheduler
lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1)

# Train the model
history = clf.fit(
    train_x, train_y, 
    epochs=50, 
    batch_size=32, 
    validation_data=(valid_x, valid_y),
    callbacks=[early_stopping, lr_scheduler],
    verbose=1
)

This is snippet of code showing the configuration and fitting the model. As you can see the loss function is being set with method .compile(). The "custom_loss" is the name of the function.
The issue is I can't come up with such a function "custom_loss" that will meet my requirement for ROC AUC. The nature of the loss function is that the smaller the loss is the better the model performs. In this case I want to use rather NEGATIVE ROC AUC score.
I have researched about how to setup the loss function. But I could not make it.
This is what I have tried so far.
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true, axis=1)
    y_pred  = tf.squeeze(y_pred, axis=1)

    # Calculate ROC AUC score
    m = tf.keras.metrics.AUC()
    m.update_state(y_true, y_pred)

    # Take negative of ROC AUC as loss
    print("result: ",m.result())
    return -(m.result())
    

When I run it, I get this error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[39], line 5
      3 pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
      4 with timer("Pipeline total time"):
----> 5     main(debug= False)

Cell In[4], line 165, in main(debug)
    163     predictors = list(filter(lambda v: v not in del_features, df.columns))
    164     cat_cols = list(df.select_dtypes("object").columns)
--> 165     model = kfold_lightgbm_sklearn(df, cat_cols)
    171 #with timer("Feature importance assesment"):
    172     
    173  #   get_features_importances(predictors, model)
    178 with timer("Submission"):

Cell In[18], line 100, in kfold_lightgbm_sklearn(***failed resolving arguments***)
     97 lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1)
     99 # Train the model
--> 100 history = clf.fit(train_x, train_y, 
    101                   epochs=50, 
    102                   batch_size=32, 
    103                   validation_data=(valid_x, valid_y),
    104                   callbacks=[early_stopping, lr_scheduler],
    105                   verbose=1)
    108 fitted_models.append(clf)
    110 if EVALUATE_VALIDATION_SET:
    111     # Obtain probabilities for each class

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/base_optimizer.py:571, in BaseOptimizer._filter_empty_gradients(self, grads, vars)
    567 filtered = [
    568     (g, v) for g, v in zip(grads, vars) if g is not None
    569 ]
    570 if not filtered:
--> 571     raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable.")
    572 if len(filtered) < len(grads):
    573     missing_grad_vars = [
    574         v for g, v in zip(grads, vars) if g is None
    575     ]

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable.

I have used information from sources [like](https://saturncloud.io/blog/creating-custom-loss-functions-in-kerastensorflow/
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile).
If you know how to do that, thanks for taking your time.

It's because, tf.keras.metrics.AUC() is metrics class not loss and it is not differentiable.  You can't use it.

@Innat         Thanks for the reply. I have had figured it myself later. I am going to use binary cross-entropy loss function which is used in binary classification.
